# How to add a single js file to my npm dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to add a dependency to my package.json for my reactjs/webpack app. This is just a local file in my project but not a projectsource file.
When I try in package.json:

```
"dependencies":
{
    "somemodule":"location_in_my_project/myfile.js"
}
```

I get an npmerror: 'not a package myfile.js'. Is it possible to inject this file into my project through npm?

Comment: It seems like an unusual thing to do, why not simply import or require your file? Npm is meant to be used for managing packages, no need for it if your files are in the same package already

Comment: 'dependencies' in package.json is telling NPM what packages should install while we run 'npm install'... So type local file without publish it won't work...

If you wanna use your file as a local package.You can make the below structure: myPackage/myFile.js then run 'npm link' in myPackage